# SAS lag function where only first row of data is known?

Tags: sas

this should be very simple but I'm having trouble. I have something like

```
data data;
   infile datalines delimiter=','; 
   input num    total   N   want;;
   datalines;                      
num total   N   want
633 3000    2367    2367
450 3000    .   1734
22  3000    .   1284
11  3000    .   1262
10  3000    .   1251
9   3000    .   1241
4   3000    .   1232
5   3000    .   1228
1   3000    .   1223
5   3000    .   1222
;
run;
```

I want to fill in the missing, where I take the previous row N-num to give me my new want. So N1 should be 2367, 1734, 1284 etc.

I try :

```
data data1;
set data;
if N=. then want=lag(N)-lag(num);
run;
```

but always get an error, as if it is trying to compute the lag globally rather than starting at the top row then moving thru. Any advice? Maybe even using proc sql?

Comment: I cannot figure out from your description what result you actually want.  You normally should never run LAG() conditionally like you are doing.  What you retrieve with it depends on what you pass in from previous executions, so skipping one execution means you cannot retrieve that value since it was never passed in.

Comment: I will try to make more clear, I'll make a 'want' variable

Comment: You do not seem to be using the variable TOTAL at all.  Is the input just the variable NUM and the initial value 2,367?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want to RETAIN a NEW variable.  (RETAIN does not work very well for variables that are coming in from the source dataset since when the next observation is read the retained value is overwritten.)

So start with a dataset with just the two variables.

```
data have;
   input num total;
datalines;                      
633 3000
450 3000
22  3000
11  3000
10  3000
9   3000
4   3000
5   3000
1   3000
5   3000
;
```

Now you can create a new variable that subtracts NUM.  Let's call this new variable REMAINDER.

```
data want;
  set have;
  if _n_=1 then remainder=total;
  remainder + -num ;
run;
```

The [SUM statement](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/n1dfiqj146yi2cn1maeju9wo7ijs.htm) automatically retains the variable you are summing into.

Result:

```
Obs    num    total    remainder

  1    633     3000       2367
  2    450     3000       1917
  3     22     3000       1895
  4     11     3000       1884
  5     10     3000       1874
  6      9     3000       1865
  7      4     3000       1861
  8      5     3000       1856
  9      1     3000       1855
 10      5     3000       1850
```

Or if you would rather subtract the previous value of NUM you could either just write the observations before you do the subtraction.

```
  output;
  remainder + -num;
```

Or use the LAG() function to subtract the previous value.  LAG() on the first observation will return a missing value which we be treated as zero by the SUM statement.

```
  remainder + -lag(num) ;
```

Results:

```
Obs    num    total    remainder

  1    633     3000       3000
  2    450     3000       2367
  3     22     3000       1917
  4     11     3000       1895
  5     10     3000       1884
  6      9     3000       1874
  7      4     3000       1865
  8      5     3000       1861
  9      1     3000       1856
 10      5     3000       1855
```

Comment: this is really close, however it looks like it's lag(remainder) - num. I need lag(remainder)-lag(num)

Comment: Add an OUTPUT before the SUM statement so that the observation is written with the value of REMAINDER from before the value is subtracted.

Comment: as you can probably tell I am not a good SAS user.. I tried and failed, thanks for the help though Tom!

Comment: Is your initial value 3,000 or 2,367? I cannot see any way to get it to work if 3,000 is the initial value.

Comment: the initial is technically 3000, but it is largely unimportant. I just want current row = previous row remainder - num (except the first row). Basically, in excel this would be crazy easy, where you just make the previous row subtraction formula and fill down the spreadsheet.. I'm surprised there's not a quick and easy way in SAS

Comment: That is exactly what retaining a variable's value across observations does.  At the start of this iteration the variable has previous value.  Do not think in terms of spreadsheets.  Think in terms of a data step operation on each observations one by one.

Comment: Where did you get 2,367 if not by subtracting NUM (633) from TOTAL?  Where did you get 1,734 if not by subtracting the previous value of NUM (633).  Why would you subtract 633 twice?  Please post details of what you want to do.